# AWS iOS SDK, The service configuration is `nil

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I need to create a platform endpoint in AWS for SNS push notifications.

In order to register the device to get the push notifications, I need to send the device ID to SNS, Im not using cognito, I want to upload the token using the AWS SDK from the phone:

> AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput

when I try to register with:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@", deviceToken);

/* This is the code to actually register the device with Amazon SNS Mobile Push based on the token received */

NSString * myArn = @"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789123:app/APNS_SANDBOX/AmazonMobilePushExample";

NSLog( @"Submit the device token [%@] to SNS to receive notifications.", [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken] );

AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput *platformEndpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
platformEndpointRequest.customUserData = @"MyUserID;iPhone5";
platformEndpointRequest.token = [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken];
platformEndpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = myArn;


//THIS LINE CRASHING
AWSSNS *snsManager = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];


//    [snsManager createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest];
```

}

But I get the crash error:

> 'The service configuration is `nil`. You need to configure `awsconfiguration.json`, `Info.plist` or set `defaultServiceConfiguration` before using this method.'

So, how to configure either my plist of my method directly with out cognito?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was needed was to set the

> AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager

as Below:

```
- (void)awsStartWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

// Set the log level
[AWSLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AWSLogLevelVerbose;

// Login
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                     initWithAccessKey:@"AKIAIxxxYYYA"
                                                     secretKey:@"Tx0vhKv1xMaaabbbbccccM5+3R9lEitw2Hzw"];


AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]
                                          initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPSoutheast2
                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

// Create SNS Client

AWSSNS *snsManager = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];


/* This is the code to actually register the device with Amazon SNS Mobile Push based on the token received. */
AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput* platformEndpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
platformEndpointRequest.customUserData = @"kUniqueID";     // It could be anything.
platformEndpointRequest.token =  [self deviceTokenAsString:deviceToken];         // Device Token No for APNS
platformEndpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = @"arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:86434343191:app/APNS_SANDBOX/ios_lambada";



[snsManager createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest completionHandler:^(AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"errore : %@", error);
}];

}
```